# Eliminating models that reference each other in creating thousands of watched scopes with angular

Tags: c#, angularjs

I currently have a database system set up with three models.  Lets call these models Members, Positions, and Teams.  The models are set up so that Members reference Positions (for a Member can be assigned to one or more Positions), the Teams also reference Positions (as a Team can have one ore more Positions assigned to it) an the Positions in turn reference both Members (who can be assigned to Positions) and Teams (which again, can have several Positions assigned to it).  I have the functionality to edit these on all different levels.

My issue is regarding the number of scopes I currently have in my "Members" section.  I use a simple `ng-repeat` list to populate the data from my server (which currently has about 30 Members).  I have about 7500 scopes on the page, because the Member references Positions which reference both Members and Teams, which in turn reference Positions again, and so on until I have completely exhausted my Members/Positions/Teams Model.  I have been working on this for a couple days now, and am trying to avoid creating three new "TemporaryModels" just for this page.  Is there a standard for dealing with multiple models that reference each other?

Comment: Could one-time binding be a solution? Maybe the way you're displaying all the data could be changed? Made simpler? Are you displaying everything as a tree? Maybe you could use ng-if to display subdata only when the user needs it, using a collapse/expand strategy?

Comment: Thanks for the response. One-time binding is not a solution, because the tables functionality allow them to be manipulated. The way I am displaying the data unfortunately will have to stay the same as well. I do believe the models/controllers can be made simpler, but that is outside of what I am allowed to do. I tried `ng-if`, which worked well, however, when attempting to post changes to the database I am catching a 400 error every time.

I was able to reduce my Teams tab (populated with Members\Positions) down to about 300 scoped variables, although I think it was largely accidental.

Comment: I don't see how using ``ngIf`` has anything to do with a 400 error. You should maybe investigate that part.

Comment: Other than that, what you could do is disable watchers when you don't need them, and enable them when you want to update specific models. That requires some tweaking of Angular's digest process and a good understanding of how it works. Basically, you can just remove watchers from any scope, save them, and reset them when you need them again. I recently implemented a optimized ngRepeat based on that idea.

Comment: Essentially, I have a scope coming back that is a model that ends up looking like this:

`Member.Positions[].Teams[].Positions[].Members[].Positions[]` because of the way multiple models are linked together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jlowcs suggested, the 400 error was hitting because I was putting an ng-if on a parent class of a button that was passing my data through my controller.

Moving past there -- I found my performance issues were largely cleared up by replacing all my `ng-show` tags with `ng-if` tags.  I have been investigating why changing `ng-if` into `ng-show` would ultimately remove over 7,000 `$scope`'d variables(largely repeats of themselves), and have not come up with  a significantly understandable explanation.

Comment: ng-if removes elements (and their watch'ed values) from the dom, at the expense of recreating them when the conditional changes.  ng-show keeps the dom elements in place, but also has to keep changing any watched values.